# Folder name is B&W, how use the & in a link?

Tags: php

```
function MenuPhoto() {                                                                          
$dir = opendir('' .$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/content/photos/');

    while(false != ($entry = readdir($dir))) {

        if($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {

            echo '<a href="index.php?page=photothingy&folder=' . $entry . '" class="menu">' . $entry . '</a> &nbsp;' . "\n"; 

      } 

    }
    closedir($dir);
}
```

I want to scan a  folder for it's subfolders and print the folder name as a link. One of the folders is called "B&W" (black and white). The url get's cut off after te B.

How do i get this to work? Help would be apreciated.

Comment: urlencode() the string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[URLEncode](https://www.php.net/urlencode) the `$entry` string in the href, like this:

```
echo '<a href="index.php?page=photothingy&folder=' 
    . urlencode($entry) . '" class="menu">' . $entry 
    . '</a> &nbsp;' . "\n";
```

**EDIT**
You might also want to [HTMLEntities](https://www.php.net/htmlentities) the `$entry` in the html, like this:

```
echo '<a href="index.php?page=photothingy&folder=' 
    . urlencode($entry) . '" class="menu">' . htmlentities($entry) 
    . '</a> &nbsp;' . "\n";
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! 
Works now, thanks!

Had been looking into htmlentities() but left out urlencode().